# Support of third party payment methods in B2B apps

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, b2b, apple-vpp

Will apple B2B apps support external payment methods instead of In-App purchase? I need to provide upgrades for paid users. The distribution method used is apple-vpp. Since apple takes 30% commission for in-app purchase, I want to know wether we can add third party payments for apps distributed via apple-vpp.

Comment: Please mention the scenario in your application which requires the payments.

Comment: If you are using VPP why would users need to upgrade to add features - You can simply ship the app with all features enabled and the volume purchaser pays you directly outside of the App Store.  It is permitted for B2B apps to be free on the VPP Store and for you to receive payment directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does not allow third party payment integrations if there is no physical exchange of goods or services. If your application only allows some features only after some subscription then the apple is going to reject the application. If you are paying someone in return of any physical goods like shopping applications or in return of some services then the application can user third party payment methods.

Please refer below link

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/97423

Comment: Will this be applicable for apps distributed via apple volume purchase program?

Comment: Yes. This will be applicable to the apple VPP also. If you are having an Apple Enterprise account and you are distributing without App Store then you can user third party payments.